# What is the difference between real value and abs value?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, vectors

I am confused here, though I have been reading about it for years. What is the difference between a real value and an absolute value? For example, when do we take the absolute value of pressure or the real value of pressure in acoustics?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Comment: What about the definition of the absolute value is unclear to you? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the difference in real life situation between absolute value and real value.

Comment: The absolute value will give you the maximum (peak) pressure, while the real will give you also the time dependence.

Answer (score 2):

Difference between real and absolute value in general: Look at count_to_10 's answer.

For acoustics and preasure measurement: Absolute pressure - pressure against perfect vacuum.
Real pressure: Usually defined as the pressure against a reference-environment. Also called differential pressure. For example the pressure of the air inside a football against the ambient pressure.

Comment: So the pressure microphone usually measures Absolute pressure?

Comment: Depends on the microphone. Some measure the difference against the environment by connecting the environment (or any other reference-volume) and the volume where the pressure has to be measured by a tube (only separated by the sensor). This is called differential pressure. Absolut pressure sensors measure against a perfect vacuum. Relative pressure sensors measure the pressure against ambient conditions.

Comment: This is interesting, So we have three types of pressure measurement 1. Relative (ambient condition), 2. Diffrential (reference environment) and Absolut (vaccum). The first two we use real value of pressure and for the third we use absolut value of pressure?

Comment: Well... Pressure measurement is always in relation to a reference-value. The three kinds of measurement just define different reference-values, but the way of measuring the pressure is the same. And absolute pressure is "real" pressure + reference pressure. So for example in acoustics the ambient pressure (reference pressure) is a static pressure of $p_{\infty}=101325\,Pa$. If you have a soundwave with a dynamic or "real" pressure of $p_{Sound}=1000\,Pa$ you get a total/absolute pressure of $p = p_{\infty}+p_{Sound} = 102325\,Pa$.

Comment: But take care: If calculating the Sound Pressure **Level** (SPL) the reference-pressure is NOT the ambient pressure. The SPL calculates the logarithmic loudness of a sound _relative_ to hearing threshold. Thus the reference-pressure is the sound pressure of the threshold.

Comment: So for example i have a monopole sound source p=exp(j*omega*t-k*r), in matlab/octave SPL=20*log10(abs(p)/2*10^(-5)) and pressure at   a point is P=real(p)?

Comment: Is the exp correct? Or is it supposed to be sin?

Comment: I beg your pardon it is supposed to be sin because we take the real part

Answer (score 0):

In a complex number $z=a+i b$,the real part is $a$ and abs is $\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$,.

I am not an expert of acoustics but in general, when pressure is given in complex quantity and you want to measure its magnitude then take absolute. If you are comparing two complex numbers then equate real with real and imaginary with imaginary.